# Resigning from a job that is more work than expected

Tags: resignation, overworked

I took a job five months ago, but it ended up that I am doing the job of 3 people, which was not made clear during the recruitment process (including the initial interview).

This is one of those cases where until you are inside the organisation, you cannot see how they operate.  I want to resign and go immediately, since I do not want to be brain drained as I have lost respect and trust for them.

So my question is, **How could I resign in a way that would not backfire on me even if they badmouth me since I will never ask them for a reference ?**

Answer (score 6):

You will hopefully have a contract with a notice period. You hand in your resignation according to the notice period in your contract. There is no need to give them any reasons. Just "I hereby resign from my position as ..., and my last working day will be ...".

Leaving right now without giving notice could have bad negative financial consequences for you.

On the other hand, there is a rule that is *always* recommended and that you should *always* follow: Look for a new job without telling anyone at the old company. Once you found a new job, and signed the contract, *that's* when you hand in your resignation at the old job. It's a lot harder for various reasons, some fair, some unfair, to find a new job if you voluntarily left your old one. And of course you don't get paid after leaving the old job while you search for a new one.

Comment: Overall I agree.  However, you need to have an answer for why you are leaving.  If you resign with no explanation, they'll probably ask for the reason.  If you don't have a planned response, that conversation could go poorly and reflect negatively on you.

Comment: @dan1111 agree. Maybe just a "This work is not what I was searching for" might be enough.

Comment: They can ask for the reason. You don't have to give one. This has been discussed here in other questions, and the consensus is you don't need to tell the old company anything.

Comment: @gnasher729 do you have to give them a reason?  No.  But if you want to leave on good terms it's a lot easier to give a generic answer like "I appreciate the opportunity to work here, but this job just isn't the right fit for me", rather than refusing to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get some practice on resolving this situation. To a certain extent, this can happen with almost any job if you don't speak up. This is not what you expected nor can you keep working at this pace. Of course, this could get you fired. You could wait until you have another offer. Who knows, this job could be better if they recognize they're asking you to do too much and want to keep someone who can do the work of three people. Many managers will continue to dump things on you if you never say anything. How can it be too much if you get it done?

You're not going to use them as a reference and you don't care if they bad mouth you, so getting fired is not the end of the world in this situation. You're going to have to come up with a reason for leaving. I wouldn't dwell on the negative aspects of this job. No one wants to hear you left because they made you work too much.